# How can I adjust the height of an element based on viewport size?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 3 app and a page that contains a Google map. I'd like to adjust the height of the map based on a percentage of the viewport height. At the moment I have the height hard-coded to 400px (see below). But, I'd like to use roughly 75% of the viewport height. Is there a way I can do this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="googleMap" style="height:400px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: #googleMap { height:75vh; } [Can I Use Viewport Units?](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use viewport units and vh in particular.  For older browsers just use a polyfill: http://html5polyfill.com/.  I use it for my site and it works good.